# Establish that $S$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{2}$...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $S = \{x \in \Bbb{R}^2: x = (2k, -3k),~k \in \Bbb{R}\}$
>
> a.) Establish that $S$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{2}$
>
> b.) Make a sketch depicting the subspace $S$ in the Cartesian plane.

I am new to vector spaces and subspaces. I am not quite sure how to attack the problem and would be very grateful for some insight. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Do you understand the definition of a vector subspace? Can you verify the axioms? Note that this is not a site for solving one's homework..

Comment: @PeterFranek I understand that. This is a problem similar to my homework that I found in the textbook. Just trying to understand the process so I can attempt the homework.

Comment: The way i understand vector subspaces is that the subspace is a vector space that basically exists as a subset inside of a larger vector. Both of which are closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Good start. Can you elaborate? Can you show that your set a subset of a vector space and it is closed to addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: Yep, that's the definition. So you have to confirm that S is closed under vector addition, and closed under scalar multiplication [that is, if $t$ is a real and $\mathbf{v} = (2k, -3k) \in S$ for $k$ a real, , then $t \mathbf{v} \in S$ too. What is $t \mathbf{v}$? Just expand that.]

Comment: we discussed in class  the subspace test which was checking $(c_1w_1 + c_2w_2) ∈ w$ where all $c$ scalars and $w_1,w_2 ∈ W$. But I am not exactly sure how to apply this.

Comment: That's true, and it's a concise way of putting it. It may, or may not, be easier than breaking it up into checking that two conditions are met.

Comment: Do b. first :) Plot various points for $k =-1,0, 1/2, 1, 2, \dots$.

Answer (score 0):

Here $S$ is the linear span of the set $\{(2,-3)\}\subset\mathbb R^2$, that is, $$S = \{k(2,-3) : k\in\mathbb R\}. $$
Geometrically this is just the line passing through the origin and the point $(2,-3)$. To formally show that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, though, you need to show that it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition. For the former, if $v\in S$ and $c\in\mathbb R$, $v=k(2,-3)$ so $cv=ck(2,-3)\in S$. For the latter, if $v,w\in S$, then $v=k(2,-3)$, $w=k'(2,-3)$, so $v+w=(k+k')(2,-3)\in S$.

(Note that taking $c=0$ shows that $0\in S$.)